# My Json string is not decoding using JSONSerialization.jsonObject()

Tags: json, swift, xcode, parsing, serialization

I'm receiving a valid Json string from my HTTP request which looks like this

```
"[{
    "id”:10,
    "user_id":"77da74e6-3e03-403d-9c1a-91f231233515”,
    "friend_user_id":"fc879bf5-c53d-4a4e-b3a4-dab7a8266a2r”,
    "name":"Tommie Smith”,
    "type":"active”,
    "created_at":"2018-05-02 14:53:09",
    "updated_at":"2018-05-02 14:53:09",
    "friend_user":{
        "id":"fc879bf5-c53d-4a4e-b3a4-dab7a8266a2r",
        "first_name”:”Allen”,
        "last_name”:”Williams”,
        "email”:”allen.williams@example.org",
        "date_of_birth":"1996-03-05 00:00:00",
        "created_at":"2018-05-02 14:53:07",
        "updated_at":"2018-05-02 14:53:07",
        "deleted_at":null
    }
},
{
    "id”:11,
    "user_id":"77da74e6-3e03-403d-9c1a-91f231233515”,
    "friend_user_id":"96990d13-372e-46f7-9187-94988954455b”,
    "name":"Mr. Thomas Atkins”,
    "type":"not",
    "created_at":"2018-05-02 14:53:10",
    "updated_at":"2018-05-02 14:53:10",
    "friend_user":{
        "id":"96990d13-372e-46f7-9187-94988954455b",
        "first_name”:”Trevor”,
        "last_name”:”Wright”,
        "email”:”trevor.wright@example.net",
        "date_of_birth":"1983-07-27 00:00:00",
        "created_at":"2018-05-02 14:53:08",
        "updated_at":"2018-05-02 14:53:08",
        "deleted_at":null
    }
}]"
```

I know that this is what I'm receiving as I'm using the following code to return a string with my data

```
let string = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
```

However, when I use the code below to parse my data, json returns nil

```
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: AnyObject]
```

What is wrong with this statement?

Comment: Can you check the JSON in your question. How many of the [smart quotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark#Curved_quotes_within_and_across_applications) are actually supposed to be there and how many were the result of an application translating them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please (learn to) **read** the JSON, it's pretty easy. There are only 2 (two!) different collection types:

- `{}` is dictionary, in Swift `[String: Any]`.
- `[]` is array, in Swift `[Any]` but in most cases an array of dictionaries `[[String: Any]]`.

so the JSON is clearly an array. In Swift 3+ a JSON value is **never** `AnyObject`

```
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [[String: Any]]
```

---

**Note:**

The mistaken double quotes are not the error reason, otherwise `jsonObject(with` would **`throw`** an error

Comment: Always your answer is fantastic @vadian